# MATLAB - plot multiple unconnected lines with patch and specify linecolor

Tags: matlab, colors, patch

I want to use patch to plot multiple unconnectes lines within one command. These lines have different colors that I want to specify. Unfortunately patch uses random colors in the yellow to blue area instead of my defined colors - how can I solve this?

```
clear all
close all
cla;

x=[];
y=[];
CC=[];
n=10;
for i=1:n
    % define start and end from i-th line
    x(end+1)=i;
    x(end+1)=i+1;
    % add nan to seperate lines
    x(end+1)=nan;

    % define start and end from i-th line
    y(end+1)=i;
    y(end+1)=1;
    % add nan to seperate lines
    y(end+1)=nan;

    CC(end+1,1:3)=0.1.*i;
end

%funktioniert
figure(1)
subplot(1,2,1)
h = patch(x', y', 0);
set(h,'LineWidth',2);
set(h,'cdata', CC, 'edgecolor','flat','facecolor','none')
title('wrong colors')

subplot(1,2,2)
for i=1:n
    xx=[1:3];
    yy=[i i i];
    line(xx,yy,'Color',CC(i,:))
    hold on
end
title('wanted colors')
```

Thanks a lot!
smaica

Comment: Why are you using `patch` to draw lines? This code seems overly clunky...

Comment: I found it to be a possibility to draw multiple lines in different colors within one command. I would be very thankful if you could help me with another solution!

Comment: For someone looking for a one-liner to plot, you're awfully wasteful actually setting up your data! Initialise `x` and `y` like so `x = reshape([1:n; 2:n+1; NaN(1,n)], 1, []); y = reshape([1:n; ones(1,n), NaN(1,n)], 1, [])` Then using a short loop and `line` doesn't look so bad.

Comment: This was just an example. My actual code plots >100000 lines in an updating simulation that sould not take longer than max. 1s. So the loop won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot lines, use the functions dedicated for this purpose, [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) or [`line`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html), instead of using [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html). Just change the [`'ColorOrder'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e54826) to your desired colors.

```
n = 10;
%Starting and ending point of lines in each col of x and y
x = [1:n; 2:n+1];    
y = [1:n; ones(1,n)]; 
CC = repmat(0.1:0.1:1,3,1).';   %Required colors
%Changing ColorOrder to required colors ( and turning the box (optional) )
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', CC, 'box', 'on');
line(x,y);    %or plot(x,y)
```

*Result:*

[image: result]

Comment: Also worth noting, as the OP was interested in speed, that this solution will be relatively quick because `line` is a more primitive method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine. Now my only problem is, that when I define a handle to the line plots, I can't change the color of them with the same command as Matlab says: "Error using set
There is no ColorOrder property on the Line class.". My code is: `h(:,k)=line(x,y); set(h(:,k),'ColorOrder', CC, 'box', 'on');`

Comment: [`'ColorOrder'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html) is the property of the axes, not line. The property you actually want to change, with the approach you mentioned (seems like a loop) , is `Color`, not `ColorOrder`. See [***Line Properties***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html).

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank you, but than `h(:,k) = line(nodesx',nodesy');
            set(h(:,k), 'Color', colors, 'box', 'on','LineWidth',M);`  does not work anymore: `Color value must be a 3 element vector`

Comment: @aciams How many lines are you plotting in a single iteration? You cannot set different colors for multiple lines with the `'Color'` property. And you don't need a loop here. You can plot all lines in a single go as shown in the answer. Btw  `box` is the property of the axes, not line. It has nothing to do here.

Comment: @SardarUsama I'm plotting more than 100000 lines in 400 possible colors. If I can't set different colors for these lines than unfortunately `line` is useless for me.

Comment: @aciams You *can* set using the approach I provided you in the answer